# Is there a word for "reorder and/or delete items of a list"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, lists, sort-ordering

This word must not include describing the action of adding an item to a list, duplicating items, or altering items, but rather exactly a subset of the actions {rearrange, delete}. In the past, I used 'Edit' and now am considering using 'Reorder/Delete' to be explicitly clear which is a bit unconventional.

Comment: *Reorder or Delete* (or *Reorder/Delete*).

Comment: I'm curious as to how this reordering/deletion is happening.  Is it some sort of button, that, once clicked, `regenerates` a list randomly?  Hard to see an overlap between these two distinct actions.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear as icy mentioned. Why do you need to reorder and delete items? They mean different actions and I don't understand what to reorder or rearrange has to do with to delete. Please explain in more detail. The following is the strict rule of this community. **Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered**. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Consider borrowing a verb from another discipline and defining it for your purposes early in your documentation. Verbs from landscaping come to mind, such as **prune**, although that one seems to emphasize the delete aspect over the rearrange aspect of your task. **Shape** feels close:

> "to make fit for (as a particular use or purpose)"
>   - [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shape)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider, ***update***

> To change (something) by including the most recent information.
>
> [M-W](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cut+ties)

Answer (score 0):

> **comb** – verb
>
> 1     Untangle or arrange (the hair) by drawing a comb through it
>
> 1.1   Remove something from (the hair) by drawing a comb through it: 
>       ‘she combed the burrs out of the dog’s coat’
>
> [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/comb#comb__14)

Many programming functions that clean and arrange data have the word
“comb” in their name.  Here is an official example:

> *Comb sort* is a relatively simple sorting algorithm ....
>
> [wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_sort)